# Какая библиотека лучше всего подходит для взятия информации о пользователях в telegram?

Tags: python, telegram

Дело в том, что мне прилетают контакты в телеграм. И мне нужно проверить совпадают ли имена и ники. Изначально я пытался использовать python-telegram со следующим кодом:

```
from telegram.client import Telegram


tg = Telegram(
    api_id=id,
    api_hash='hash',
    phone='phone_number',
    database_encryption_key='key',
)
tg.login()


result = tg.get_user(830189879)
result.wait()
print(result.update)
```

Но он выдаёт мне None
После пары часов страданий я перешёл на библиотеку pyrogram, но она не выдаёт about и фото возвращается в очень странной кодировке. Так же я пробовал подрубаться к api напрямую, но в документации нет примера того, как должен выглядеть url-запрос (важно! это не бот-api)
Из этого вопрос. Вы не знаете хорошей библиотечки для этой цели? Или хотя бы как должен выглядеть url запрос для метода типа `users.getFullUser`

Answer (score 1):

Используй aiogram она даст тебе то что нужно. А решить проблему твою можно очень просто с помощью базы данных sqlite3